# Criteria for an analytic function when the real and imaginary parts are $n$ dimensional

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, analytic-functions

Say we have two functions 
$$
f,g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}
$$

and we define some complex function $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ as 
$$
h(\vec x) = f(\vec x) + ig(\vec x)
$$

If $n=2$, we have an easy criteria to check if we have an analytic function in the Cauchy-Riemann equations. Is there a similar analog for $n>2$?

Comment: I doubt it. The properties of complex numbers and complex functions don't generalize to higher dimensions, at least most of them. More precisely, analytic functions are only defined on $\mathbb{C}$. As far as I know, I could be wrong

Comment: First, you need $n=2m$ and give an m-dimensional complex structure on your real space to make sense of complex-analyticity; for example you can write $z_k=x_{2k-1}+ix_{2k}$ but there are many other structures of course; once this is done, Hartogs' theorem shows that separate complex-analyticity in each complex variable (so C-R for the partial derivatives of each pair of real variables that you "join" in a complex variable) implies joint complex analyticity (namely the existence of a Taylor series around any point), so the usual C-R in pairs are still enough

Comment: @YuriyS Analyticity definitely makes sense in the $\mathbb C^n \to \mathbb C^m$ case, as Conrad mentioned. It makes sense even more generally, for example on Complex Manifolds (which have holomorphic coordinate charts to $\mathbb C^n$)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen, thanks, I stand corrected